# About tkinter scrolledtext

Tags: python, tkinter, iteration

I have a problem in using Tkinter as follows:

The following simple code is to test the scrolledtext widget. And what I need to realize is that I want the result continously (incrementally?) displayed in the scrolledtext widget, where i can clearly know which step is processing. but not to wait the whole iteration is over. It is ok when the total number of iterations is small (less than 10^5), but if the number is large (e.g. 10^8 or 10^10), it has to wait long time. Can anyone gives me some suggestions?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()

text_area = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win)

for i in range(10000000):
    text_area.insert(tk.END, "step " + str(i) + "\n")

text_area.see(tk.END)
text_area.pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.after()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

win = tk.Tk()
def add_to_frame(i):
    if i<10000000:
        text_area.insert(tk.END, "step " + str(i) + "\n")
        text_area.see(tk.END)
        win.after(1,add_to_frame,i+1)
text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win)


text_area.see(tk.END)
text_area.pack()
i=0
win.after(1,add_to_frame,i)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow, it almost works.....   Is it possible to make the cursor (focus) always appear at the end?

Comment: You wan the cursor at the end? @TaoZeng

Comment: yes,  the scrollbar does not move with the process. I have to manually move it to the end to see which step it is.

Comment: Most welcome @TaoZeng, consider accepting and upvoting the answer ```;-)```

Comment: Is it possible to display the result of any variable in another file to the scrolltext. My question is:   Image I have two python files. py1.py is the main file which contains only scrolledtext widget. And what I need to realize is that I want the result of any variable in  py2.py   to be consciously displayed in the scrolledtext widget (which is embedded in py1.py).